A priori bound of approximation solution in proof of Leray theorem
I meet a problem when reading Chemin's Mathematical Geophysics. In page 45, to prove Leray theorem (about global weak solution of Navier-Stokes equations) he constructs an ODE:
$$
(NS_{\nu,k})\begin{cases}
\dot{u}_k(t)=\nu\boldsymbol{P}_k\Delta u_k(t)+F_k(u_k(t))+f_k(t),\\
u_k(0)=\boldsymbol{P}_ku_0.
\end{cases}
$$
After showing the existence of maximal solution $u_k$ of $(NS_{\nu,k})$ in $C^{\infty}([0,T_k);\mathcal{H}_k)$, he wants to prove $T_k=+\infty$, thus he gives an estimate:
$$
\|\dot{u}_k(t)\|_{L^2}\le\nu k\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}+Ck^{\frac{d}{4}}\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}^2+\|f_k(t)\|_{L^2}.
$$
About estimate above, he says "If $\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}$ remains bounded on some interval $[0,T)$, so does $\|\dot{u}_k(t)\|_{L^2}$. Thus, for any $k$, the function $u_k$ satisfies
the Cauchy criteria when $t$ tends to $T$. Thus the solution can be extended beyond $T$. It follows that a uniform bound on $\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}$ will imply that $T_k=+\infty$". To derive this bound, in page 46 he gives another estimate:
$$
\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}^2+\nu\int_0^t\|\nabla u_k(t')\|_{L^2}^2dt'\le\|u_k(0)\|_{L^2}^2+\frac{C}{\nu}\int_0^t\|f_k(t')\|_{\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}'}^2dt'+\nu\int_0^t\|u_k(t')\|_{L^2}^2dt'.\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
He says "Gronwall's lemma implies that $\{u_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ remains uniformly bounded in $\mathcal{H}$ for all time, hence $T_k=+\infty$".
My problem is that by using Gronwall's lemma, I can only find for any fixed $t$, $\{u_k(t)\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence (about spacial variable $x$) in $\mathcal{H}$. But I think the uniform boundness we need should be about $t$ (i.e. there exists constant $C'$ s.t. $\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}\le C'$), and I don't know how to find this $C'$ from (1). The following is what I've done:
Let $y:=\int_0^t\|u_k(t')\|_{L^2}^2dt', A(t):=\|u_k(0)\|_{L^2}^2+\frac{C}{\nu}\int_0^t\|f_k(t')\|_{\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}'}^2dt'$, then
\begin{align*}
(1)&\Rightarrow y'\le A(t)+\nu y\\
&\Rightarrow(e^{-\nu t}y)'\le e^{-\nu t}A(t)\\
&\Rightarrow y\le e^{\nu t}\int_0^te^{-\nu s}A(s)ds
\end{align*}
Combining the result above and (1), we have
$$
\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}^2+\nu\int_0^t\|\nabla u_k(t')\|_{L^2}^2dt'\le A(t)+\nu e^{\nu t}\int_0^te^{-\nu s}A(s)ds
$$
Even if there exists a constant $C''$ s.t $0\le A(t)\le C''$, we can still only get
$$
\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}^2+\nu\int_0^t\|\nabla u_k(t')\|_{L^2}^2dt'\le C''+C''e^{\nu t}(1-e^{-\nu t})=C''e^{\nu t}
$$
where $C''e^{\nu t}$ can't be a uniform bound (about $t$) of $\|u_k(t)\|_{L^2}^2$. What's wrong here?
